# loop through url parametier and pass it in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, mongoose

I am trying to loop through all my post requests and adding them all up at once.
What is the best way to do this ?

Here is my Form, and the data i get.

```
var Form = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    club: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: String
    },
    partyInfo: {
        type: [{
            entry: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            },
            student: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            minAge: {
                type: Number,
            }
        }],
    }
});
```

Now i could go like this through every one in my `FormController`

```
let title = urlParams.title;
let club = urlParams.club;
```

But this would't be this nice.

Here is my full controller.

```
exports.contact = function(req, res) {
    let urlParams = req.query;

    let title = urlParams.title;
    let club = urlParams.club;

    let formParams = new Form({
        'title': title,
        'club': club
    });

    formParams.save(function (err) {
    });
    res.json(formParams);

};
```

I am not sure how i could do this well, any suggestions ? 
Is it better to loop the query or save first everything in an array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Mongoose, you can use the validation provided by it: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

If you pass `urlParams` to the Schema, it will remove all keys that are not part of the schema. And all keys that are part of the schema can be automatically validated by Mongoose.

Example:

```
exports.contact = function(req, res) {
    let formParams = new Form(req.query);
    formParams.save(function (err) {
    });
    res.json(formParams);
};
```